# How to add an API layer on top of an existing Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

There are some questions regarding this but all of them include making changes to the existing routes or creating APIs from scratch. What I would like to do is seperate the API completely under a different subroute. Something like this:

`/users/:id` -> Regular Rails server

`/api/v1.0/users/:id` -> Modified API layer which access the models and controllers of the base Rails server

I would really like to separate the logic of the API away from the Rails base implementaiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure at routes.rb:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

If you want to use `API` instead of `Api`, at `config/initializers/inflectors.rb` add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym   'API'
end
```

Your users_controller must be in `app/api/v1/controllers`, and look like this:

```
module API
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit**: you can find more options at [railscasts: 350-rest-api-versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning)

Comment: oh inflectors, it's a concept i haven't come across yet. I will check it out

Comment: thanks for the edit, the controller example makes it very clear. I will try out a route now

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this out? [Api on Rails](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_one)

Especially pay attention to how routes.rb is laid out in chapter 2. It shows how you can use scopes and namespaces to create routes to different subdirectories in your project.